# Accessing extended User class fields

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I created my own UserProfile by extending the default User class provided by Django:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # extended fields here
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
```

I have within my users/admin.py:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["user"]
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
# admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

I am able to see email, `first_name`, and `last_name` within my admin page because they are provided by the built in User class. However I was wondering how I can add `bio` as well from `UserProfile` class.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `list_display`, add `userprofile`

```
list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','userprofile')
```